# Heroku / Main domain & subdomain

Tags: heroku, subdomain, cname

Playing around with heroku;

Let's say my site is in production on one of our servers; at **www.something.com**.

I'd like to have **updrage-dev-version.something.com** to point to my heroku stack.

Is it something that can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can definitely be done. You just need to set a `CNAME` entry for the `updrage-dev-version` subdomain pointing to `myapp.herokuapp.com`.

[Here's a good example on configuring your domain records](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter).

Comment: The only caveat has to do with naked domains, as detailed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords

Comment: Seems obvious sure. Not experienced enough. But as far as I've read, they kind of explains you to first set a 'top' domain, then it'll check if the subdomain is pointing right. So in the end, the subdomain becomes the 'top' domain ? (getting it all from there https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: If you haven't found what you are looking for, please clarify that question.

Comment: @Ben Added a link to a guide.